# Cant find postgres sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence

Hibernate can not find my sequence, the exception is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
              ERROR: relation "default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq" does not exist
```

OK, i try it myself and connect do database:

```
mydb=# CREATE SEQUENCE "default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq" INCREMENT BY 1 
               MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE START WITH 1 NO CYCLE;
ERROR:  relation "default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq" already exists
mydb=# select nextval('default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq');
ERROR:  relation "default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: select nextval('default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq');
```

Do i have a sequence and what is its name?

Comment: You have a schema called `default` ?

Comment: Yes i have a schema called "default"! I need the sequence in a schema.

Comment: Please try creating the sequence without `" "`. Also, `default` is a reserved keyword both in ANSI SQL standard and PostgreSQL. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: hm, default is a keyword, ill try `"default".menuite...`

Comment: @ConsiderMe Thats it, define this as an answer and ill accept it.

Comment: Well this is something. I consider this to be unfair not to even notice my answer. But anyways, it's your call to choose I guess ... :-)

Comment: @ConsiderMe DRTL sorry, noticed too late that I checkd other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

What you did is you actually created a sequence with the name of `"default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq"` inside the current schema (probably `public`).

**Information & Approach**

`default` is a reserved keyword both in ANSI SQL Standard and PostgreSQL.

[From the Postgres manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

```
Key Word    PostgreSQL  SQL:2011    SQL:2008    SQL-92
DEFAULT     reserved    reserved    reserved    reserved
```

If you want to `CREATE SEQUENCE` in your schema which can only have a name of `"default"` then you need to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "default".menuitem_menuitem_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 
               MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE START WITH 1 NO CYCLE;
```

Additional quotes around your sequence name aren't really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

The quoting must be made on each qualifier separetely:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "default"."menuitem_menuitem_id_seq" 
INCREMENT BY 1 
MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE 
START WITH 1 
NO CYCLE;
```

Otherwise a sequence named `default.menuitem_menuitem_id_seq` will be created in the current schema